# Date Range in Bootstrap DatePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Which bootstrap files need to include and how to implement the bootstrap datepicker?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Common/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is the code:

```
 <div id="yeadDropdown" class="drpDownMarginAdjust">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which datepicker plugin you are using. Because, there are many bootstrap datepickers.

But usually to initiate datepicker you need to execute this javascript code:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Before executing this code add "datepicker" class to your inputs, like this:

```
<input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" />
```